# Handle two fact TABLE

Tags: qlikview

I have two facts

I use the following code to load from QVD

```
Vente:
LOAD PrixUnitaireArticle,
     PrixArticleHT,
     PrixRevientTTC,
     MargeHT,
     MargeTTC,
     ValeurRevientHT,
     ValeurRevientTTC,
     ValeurMargeHT,
     ValeurMargeTTC,
     PrixVenteHT,

FROM
E:\QVD TEST\VenteFULL.qvd
(qvd);


LOAD
  [idObjCA]
      ,[CA TTC]
      ,[VAL MRG TTC]
      ,[CA HT]
      ,[VAL MRG HT]
      ,[Rayon]
      , [Date Time Budget]
      ,[Code Site Budget]
      ,[Code Rayon]

FROM
E:\QVD TEST\Budget.qvd
(qvd)
```

When I load data , I got the following shema , there are too many loops .
[image]

How can I improve my data model ?

Comment: First, show all your scheme, not part of it, to get a better idea of how to help you....for example -- do you have any sync tables?
Second, try renaming one of the link fields.
Third, maybe a Link Table is a good Idea here?...

Comment: Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337272/handling-multiple-fact-tables-in-qlikview). I think if you follow the steps in my answer to that question, your problem will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [linktable](http://www.qliktips.com/2011/05/rules-for-creating-keylink-table-in.html) which contains all the fields that are in double and then remove it from the source table. 
You have to create key in each source table and put it in the linktable.

Here a example of a good linktable schema:

[image: Linktable Schema]